java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver in Amazon Linux Machine
I am working on Amazon Linux machine. I have installed all the required libraries still getting odbc error. I have tried multiple jars files still no success. need help for this issue.

Python version = 3.8.0
Pyspark = 3.5.1
Odbc = 17

sparksession config code part:
.config("spark.jars", "/home/user/scripts/sqljdbc42.jar")
.config("spark.jars", "/home/user/scripts/mssql-jdbc-12.6.1.jre11.jar")

url = "jdbc:sqlserver://123.42.3.10:1433;database=demo"

df = (spark.read
.format("jdbc")
.option("driver", "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver")
.option("url", url)
.option("dbtable", f"({dtable}) AS subquery")  # just pass table_name if not using query
.option("user", user)
.option("password", password)
.option("encrypt", "true")
.option("trustServerCertificate", "true")
.load()
.limit(10)
)

install mysql odbc 17 for sql server as well odbcinst -q -d above command return [PostgreSQL] [MySQL] [ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]
getting error:
An error occurred while calling o53.load.
: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:445)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:592)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:525)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.DriverRegistry$.register(DriverRegistry.scala:46)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCOptions.$anonfun$driverClass$1(JDBCOptions.scala:103)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCOptions.$anonfun$driverClass$1$adapted(JDBCOptions.scala:103)
at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCOptions.\<init\>(JDBCOptions.scala:103)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCOptions.\<init\>(JDBCOptions.scala:41)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcRelationProvider.createRelation(JdbcRelationProvider.scala:34)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:346)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:229)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.$anonfun$load$2(DataFrameReader.scala:211)
at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:211)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:172)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:374)
at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)

I have tried multiple jars files as mentioned above.
